# Proper subgroups and cyclic properties

Tags: abstract-algebra

Problem: If every proper subgroup of $G$ is cyclic, must $G$ also be cyclic? Prove or give a counter-example.

I'm not sure where to start on this one to solve it, but I have some knowledge that I think will be valuable to do so.

I know that every group $G$ has two trivial subgroups: {${e}$} and $G$ itself. I also know every other subgroup that aren't these are so-called *proper* subgroups

Will anyone be willing to help me solve this problem? Any help appreciated.

Comment: The smallest possible counterexample is a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** All groups of prime order are cyclic. Can you find a noncyclic group whose only proper subgroups are groups of prime order (or trivial)?

**More concrete hint:** Think about your favorite noncyclic groups of small order. What proper subgroups do they have?

As a remark, a proper subgroup is usually considered to simply be a subgroup $H\subseteq G$ which is not all of $G.$ So if $G$ is nontrivial, $\{e\}$ would be a proper subgroup. Of course, $\{e\}$ is always cyclic.

Comment: Does this have something to do with this "Klein four-group" I keep seeing?

Comment: @Propaloo you don't necessarily have to know about the Klein four-group in order to solve this problem, but that's a good example. The Klein four-group $V_4$ can be written concretely as $V_4 = \{(1,1),(-1,1),(1,-1),(-1,-1)\},$ with group operation being coordinate-wise multiplication.

Comment: Does $G = {{(1,3,5,7)}}$ under multiplication $mod  8$ work?

Comment: @Propaloo That $G$ is isomorphic to $V_4.$ Do you mean is it a counterexample to the claim? Have you calculated the subgroups? Have you checked if it is cyclic? It should not be hard to do these calculations by hand given how small $G$ is.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* There is an abelian counterexample and a nonabelian counterexample. Both well-knonw groups with very small order.